# Using ParamConverter from a $_POST request (not from URL)

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, symfony-routing

Is it possible tu use the @ParamConverter annotation in Symfony2 to convert a parameter send via the $_POST request into an Entity?

All examples given in the symfony2 documentation convert entities from parameter defined in the route.

Setting something like that:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @ParamConverter("user", class="BvStandardServiceBundle:User", options={"id" = "userId"})
 */
public function userAction(User $user)
{
}
```

If I call this route with an id in the `userId` $_POST param, it results in:

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request
>   information.

Comment: Have you tried to add @Method("POST") on the controller signature? Antoher way may be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186731/using-custom-paramconverter-for-post-request-in-symfony-2

Comment: Use custom param converter http://stfalcon.com/en/blog/post/symfony2-custom-paramconverter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paramConverter of symfony run only for request param into the URL unfortunately : [ParamConverter specification](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

Framework work directly with the URL param for search the association between param url and paramConverter. If you don't use a param into your URL, the engine symfony will don't search association with your paramConverter.

You can also view the kernel.event for this which need request for work : [Class : ParamConverterListener.php](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ParamConverterListener.php)

Answer (score -2):

I use https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle to convert JSON data to Doctrine ORM entities and then save them to DB.